# How to sort my SQL table datas in category wise

Tags: php, sql, create-table

I am trying to create a music site, I need to sort my table data in category wise.

Like English, Chinese, Hindi etc.

but my data's on one page

I need 3 different pages

example.com/englishsongs.php

example.com/chinesmusic.php

example.com/hindimusic.php

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (

`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

`namemovie` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`releaseyear` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`musiccategory` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`musiclink` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: you want to sort in ascending and descending ordeR?

Comment: Are those values stored in the musiccategory column?

Comment: Please show some sample data here.  Your question is incomplete.

Comment: `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` you know that Hindi and Chinise are not allowed in a latin charset right?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query this will give actual result which you want

```
 SELECT namemovie, releaseyear, musiccategory,  musiclink FROM players GROUP BY musiccategory, namemovie,  releaseyear, musiclink
```

Comment: [musiccategory]

Comment: what does mean [musiccategory] ??

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE musiccategory= 'ENGLISH/HINDHI/CHINES'

Comment: For example if you want English songs... Then request like,

SELECT * FROM players WHERE musiccategory= 'English'